# Consume basic auth rest api. working in seperate Java program but not in Grails application

Tags: java, grails

I am calling basic auth rest api. seperate java program is working properly but when I add it into Grails application it throws exception saying 
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SocketException occurred when processing request: [GET]
Message: Connection reset

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient(); 
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://....")
                .get()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic Q...")
                .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .addHeader("Postman-Token", "77768b44-678d-4803-8ea2-46767192b161")
                .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: Ramp up the logging in OK and see if that gives any further clues. What are the differences between the grails and java version then?  Same OK version?  Same Java/JDK/keystores/...

Comment: @cfrick Thanks for reply. I am using Grails 2.3.6 and Java 1.7, I have also tried same api with HttpUrlConnection and Spring Rest Template but getting same exception in both the cases.On the other side this api is successfully getting called in standalone Java program.

Comment: Ramp up the logging then. I hope the 1.7 JDK is recent one or you will get problems with TLS.  I assume this is the same JDK for the grails and the java app?

Comment: @cfrick I addressed issue .I think the issue is with combination of Grails2.3.6 and Java7 version.  I have build it on Grails 2.4.0 and Java 8 and It is working properly. Thanks for guidance